# Compilation fails with #include "..." but not with #include <...>

Tags: c, gcc, opengl, include

I'm currently toying around with the C library [NanoVG](https://github.com/memononen/nanovg) library. The library depends on OpenGL fucntions and has 2 header files `nanovg.h` and `nanovg_gl.h`. The latter file contains part of the implementation. For convenience, I have placed these two header files in `/usr/include/nanovg`.

When I try to compile the following code to an object file, gcc does not complain:

```c
// working.c
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <nanovg/nanovg.h>
#define NANOVG_GL3_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <nanovg/nanovg_gl.h>
```

(Command: `gcc -c working.c -o working.o`)

Now, I copy the header files from `/usr/include/nanovg/` to the working directory, and replace the code with:

```c
// notworking.c
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include "nanovg.h"
#define NANOVG_GL3_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "nanovg_gl.h"
```

(Command: `gcc -c notworking.c -o notworking.o`)

Gcc now complains that some OpenGL functions are not declared:

```
... (many more similar complaints)
src/nanovg_gl.h: In function ‘glnvg__renderDelete’:
src/nanovg_gl.h:1540:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘glDeleteBuffers’; did you mean ‘glSelectBuffer’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1540 |   glDeleteBuffers(1, &gl->fragBuf);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
```

Why does one file compile smoothly but not the other?

**A bit deeper:**
Using the `cpp` tool, I found that the difference between the two pre-processed files is limited to # directives but I don't see any difference as far as the "C content" goes. Below is a snippet of the pre-processed `working.c`. If I add the # lines from the pre-processed `notworking.c`, then gcc no longer compiles the pre-processed `working.c` and complains about a missing declaration for `glDeleteBuffers`.

```c
// ... 
 if (gl == 
// # 1533 "src/nanovg_gl.h" 3 4 // <- uncomment this line and glDeleteBuffers is considered missing by gcc
          ((void *)0)
// # 1533 "src/nanovg_gl.h" // <- idem
              ) return;

 glnvg__deleteShader(&gl->shader);



 if (gl->fragBuf != 0)
  glDeleteBuffers(1, &gl->fragBuf); // <- the function that gcc complains about is here
// ...
```

**Edit:** Just to make sure that I did not do anything sneaky that might have caused the difference, I followed the following steps which hopefully should be reproducible on another computer:

1. GCC version: `gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0`
2. Copy the version of `GL/gl.h` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/4tn4qbBK) to working directory and call it `glfoo.h`
3. Copy the headers of `nanovg` (as found in the repo) to `/usr/include/nanovg/` and `nanovg/` (relative to working directory).
4. Save the following as  `test.c` in the working dir:

```c
#include "glfoo.h"
#include <nanovg/nanovg.h>
#define NANOVG_GL3_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <nanovg/nanovg_gl.h>
```

4. Run `gcc -c test.c -o test.o` => compilation works
5. Replace <...> with ".." on lines 2 and 4 and run command => compilation fails.

Just tried these exact steps and I was able to reproduce it.

Comment: Maybe copy the entire folder `nanovg` and place it in your working directory and use it as `"nanovg/nanovg.h"`? Are you sure those headers are independent and don't depend on anything else?

Comment: Open gl.h to check that `glDeleteBuffers` is actually declared.  I know nothing about opengl, but it seems that some versions have this and some don't . For example [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/mesa/+/457812d99a213dedf1c4cd38018ff48118d0c44f/include/GL/gl.h) does not declare it (while it does declare the suggested `glSelectBuffer`). I have no idea however why changing from `<...>` to `"..."` would cause a different version of GL/gl.h to be included.  My guess (and Occam's razor suggests) would be that that is not the only thing you have changed.

Comment: ... does it work if you include `<GL/glext.h>` before including `"nanovg_gl.h"`?

Comment: @Zoso: no, copying the entire include folder does not make a difference it seems. ``nanovg.h`` does not contain any ``#include`` statements so I assume it does not depend on anything else.

@Clifford: yes indeed, my ``GL/gl.h`` does not declare ``glDeleteBuffers`` but I'm really curious why that does matter in one case but not the other. Including ``GL/glext.h`` does not help but with ``GL/glew.h`` (before ``GL/gl.h``), the errors do go away.

Comment: The question here is not why `notworking.c` is not working, but _why `working.c` is actually working_, because `glDeleteBuffers` should not be in `gl.h`, and it also is not in `glext.h` (unless you `#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES`, which you should **never** do). You always have to use a GL loader like GLEW or glad to access every function above GL 1.1. And the nanovg source code actually expects you to use a loader which either provides the GL symbols directly, or uses some preprocessor macros to redifne them (like most loaders do).

Comment: Edited to add steps to reproduce. Hopefully, that addresses Clifford's guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After investigating this a bit I found the solution. `gcc` **does not apply the same warning level to system headers** as it does for "normal" files (this is mainly because system headers are sometimes doing weird things which are not backed up by the C standard, but are "safe" for the platform they are coming with).

The [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) states (emphasis mine):

> `-Wsystem-headers`:
>
> Print warning messages for constructs found in system header files. **Warnings from system headers are normally suppressed, on
> the assumption that they usually do not indicate real problems and
> would only make the compiler output harder to read.** Using this
> command-line option tells GCC to emit warnings from system headers as
> if they occurred in user code. However, note that using -Wall in
> conjunction with this option does not warn about unknown pragmas in
> system headers—for that, `-Wunknown-pragmas` must also be used.

When you include nanovg via `<...>`, it is treated as a system header.

So doing `gcc -Wsystem-headers working.c` actually will bring on the warning.

Note that your code is neither working in `working.c` nor `notworking.c`, as `working.c` just hides the warning messages. The proper way to access any GL function beyond what is defined in GL 1.1 is to use the GL extension mechanism, which means you have to query the GL function pointers at run-time. Full GL loader libs like GLEW and glad can do that for you automatically. Many of these loaders (including GLEW and GLAD) work by re-`#define`-ing every GL function name to an internal function pointer, so when you include the header which comes with the loader, every GL function called in your code (and nanovg's) will be re-routed to the loader-libraries function pointers, and your code can actually work (provided you properly initialize the loader at run-time before any of the GL functions is called).

Comment: Huh, I would expect a compiler to be more selective about which warnings it suppresses in system headers. It makes sense to suppress a warning about, say, declaration of a “reserved” identifier, since system headers sometimes ought to be declaring reserved identifiers. But using an undeclared function is likely a mistake even in system headers.

Comment: Well, it is how it is. I'd rather not try to make a discussion about the usefulness of that behavior here. It would be something to discuss with the gcc developers.

Answer (score -3):

simply

```
#include <file.h>
```

include file from the path listed default to the compiler, while

```
#include "file.h"
```

include file from the current folder (where you are compiling).

As in your case , switching from <> to "" makes come files  missing which makes that compiler error coming.

Comment: No, the header files are not missing, and the compiler error message is not reporting that the files are missing. The question compares a compilation using `<` and `>` with the header files in a system location with a compilation using `"` and `"` with the header files in the source file directory. In both cases, the compiler finds the header files, so that is not the problem. The problem is that, in the latter case, the compiler reports `glDeleteBuffers` is not declared. This means the compiler is processing the headers differently depending on where they are included from.

Comment: No.  "..." searches the current folder _before_ searching the paths specified by `-i` command line switches and default system paths (in that order).   Does not answer the question, even if it were true;  gl.h is included with `<...>` and that is where `glDeleteBuffers` should be found.